# LEX and YACC : grammar implementation in NLP

Tags: ubuntu, nlp, yacc, lex

am trying to build an NLP . But the thing is that i am not able to get few things in it . For ex : if in action i say

> printf("print the third argument %s", $3) ;

then its not giving me the third argument instead it shows

> print the third argument (null)

Since i am trying to build an NLP it is important for me to include the arguments . So what should i do . Below i include some of the sample code and output :

pro.yacc file :

```
   %{
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "y.tab.h"

int yylex(void) ;
static void yyerror(char *str) 
{
    printf("yyerror : %s " , str) ;
}
%}

%error-verbose
%token ASK
%token FIELD
%token QUALIFIER
%token MOJ
%token WORD
%token TOTAL
%token TABLE
%token EOL


%% 

translate   :   select
        |   count
            ;                                                                                                                                                    


select  :    ASK QUALIFIER TABLE EOL        { printf("SELECT *  FROM %s",$3) ;} 
    |    ASK FIELD QUALIFIER TABLE EOL    { printf("SELECT DISTINCT %s FROM %s ", $2, $4) ;} 
    |    ASK QUALIFIER TABLE FIELD EOL    { printf("SELECT DISTINCT %s FROM %s ", $4, $3) ;}
    |    ASK QUALIFIER FIELD WORD FIELD QUALIFIER TABLE EOL    { printf("SELECT DISTINCT %s , %s FROM %s", $3, $5, $7) ;}        
    ;

count     :    MOJ TABLE EOL    { printf("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM %s", $2) ;}
    ;


%%


#include "lex.yy.c"
extern int yylex() ;
extern int yyparse() ;
extern FILE *yyin ;
int main() 
{
    FILE *myfile = fopen("sample.txt" , "r") ;
    if(!myfile)
    {
        printf("Can't open the file ") ;
        return -1 ;
    }
    yyin = myfile ;
    do
    {
        yyparse();
    }while(!feof(yyin)) ;
    yylex_destroy() ;
    return 0 ;
}
```

pro.lex :

```
%{
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "y.tab.h"
#include "pro.tab.h"

void yyerror(char *str) ;





int line_num = 1 ;
%}




%%

[\t] ;

"reply"    { return ASK  ; }

"display"   { return ASK  ; }

"and"   { return WORD ; } 

"of every"  { return QUALIFIER  ; }

"all"  { return QUALIFIER  ; } 

"the"  { return QUALIFIER  ; }

"every"  { return QUALIFIER  ; }    

"name"   { return FIELD ; }   

"id"   { return FIELD ; } 

"how many"   { return MOJ ; }

"book"  { return TABLE   ; }   

"."   { return EOL ; } 



%%
```

after running input file sample.txt on this with i/p :"read every book ."  ( quotes not included i get the o/p

```
                            SELECT * FROM (null)
```

. i should actually be getting book in place of (null) .  .. how do i do that ?

P.S. :  I get this null value every time i try to print that argument .. in all the grammars

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your lexical analyzer is not retaining the spelling of the words — it is simply returning a number, without making sure that the word is available other than as `yytext`.  Your grammar is not copying `yytext` as the tokens arrive.  So, if you need to keep the strings (so you can distinguish between "reply" and "display", for example — two alternative spellings for token ASK), then you have to ensure that the information is saved, copied, released.  By the time a grammar rule is operating, it may well have read more tokens — possibly even have encountered EOF.  Consequently, you normally need a more complex structure for YYSTYPE (and `%union`) so that you can get hold of the information you need later.

Answer (score 1):

Your lexer is returning a token number (`TABLE`) but your parser is trying to interpret it as a string.  Change your parse rule to

```
select  :    ASK QUALIFIER TABLE EOL        { printf("SELECT *  FROM %d",$3) ;}
```

and I think that you will see the difference.

Comment: Sir it returns SELECT * FROM 0 ... doesn't help